# How to enable overlay scrollbars in my app?

Tags: 11.04, programming, application-development, overlay-scrollbars, pygtk

I'm testing my app in Natty 2nd beta, in which most applications are showing the new overlay scroolbars, I guess only non-native GTK apps can't show it (like LibreOffice or Firefox).

My app is coded using Python and pygtk so I thought the overlay scrollbars should be enabled by default but I was wrong. I tried to set the environment variable `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR` to `1` in both terminal (previously to the app command) and inside the python code via `os.putenv()`, but it's still showing the old-fashioned scrollbars.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is quite old -- do you still have this problem with the final Natty release?

Comment: Maybe you want to use PyGI instead of PyGTK.

Comment: Are you using the `gtk_scrolled_window` widget? Or in PyGTK terms, `gtk.ScrolledWindow`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use gtk_scrolled_window widget because is the only widget that support overlay scrollbars.

Source https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana/ScrollBars

If it doesn't work try with:

```
sudo su
echo "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/80overlayscrollbars
```